# "House title", "title to the house", "title of the house"

Tags: phrase-choice, idiomatic-language

I was wondering if someone could tell me which one of the listed choices of mine would be an AmE native speaker's choice to complete the self-made sentence below:

> - I put .......... up as a collateral for a bank loan.
>
> **a)** the house title
>
> **b)** the title to the house
>
> **c)** the title of the house

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The title **to** the house

is the correct choice for this context.  Since "title" has various meanings, so the participle helps to distinguish one from another.  Here you want to specify this definition:

> [Title](http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/title) : a document which shows that someone owns property

The "title **of** the house" and  "the house title" would instead indicate you mean its formal *name*, for example "The White House", or "Wuthering Heights".

Unfortunately I don't think there is any *rule* you can memorize to help you understand this pattern with various other combinations.  It's an idiomatic expression that you have to memorize, although not one you're likely to use in common conversation unless you work in the [real estate](http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/real%20estate) industry.